# Unable to boot gigabyte brix from Windows 10 installed on SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, uefi

I have Windows 10 installed in SSD in legacy mode (not UEFI). I have connected it to gigabyte brix. When I turn on the Brix, its does not boot from SSD. Instead it gives me UEFI shell:

[image]

When I type exit and hit enter in above shell prompt, it seems to take me to BIOS which lists SSD is detected:

[image]

It does not show SSD in boot order:

[image]

I tried by turning off secure boot, but no help:

[image]

How can I enable booting from legacy mode Windows installation in my SSD and boot Brix from it?

**Update**

I did not mention exact version of BRIX. Its Gigabyte BRIX GB-BLCE-4105

After going through some reviews, I found that UEFI support is hard coded in the firmware and it simply does not support leagacy OS support.

My further questions will be:

**Q1.** Is that even possible to hardcode UEFI support and not support legacy mode at all? (I guess yes, it all depends on how firmware is coded, but need confirmation)

**Q2.** Is it fixable? With say firmware updates / flashing or some other approaches?

Comment: Your motherboard firmware does not support legacy booting -only UEFI.  That is the norm for most new motherboard firmware nowadays.  Vendors have been slowly phasing out CSM support for years.

Answer (score 0):

After going through some reviews, I found that UEFI support is hard coded in the firmware and it simply does not support leagacy OS support.

My further questions will be:

**Q1.** Is that even possible to hardcode UEFI support and not support legacy mode at all? (I guess yes, it all depends on how firmware is coded, but need confirmation)

**Q2.** Is it fixable? With say firmware updates / flashing or some other approaches?

Including screenshots of the reviews mentioning the same:

[**Review from amazon**](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07DMM7Z7N/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1#customerReviews)
[image]

**[Reviews from newegg](https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-brix-gb-blce-4105-bw/p/N82E16856164115)**

[image]

[image]

[image]